# Pasar una variable por parámertro a método push de Thymeleaf

Tags: java, java-ee, servidor, thymeleaf

Estoy intentando pasar un número que escribo en un `<input>` a un método push para poder trabajar con él, consigo ejecutar estos métodos perfectamente, pero no consigo enviar la variable.

```
<table id="configurarAutomatizacion">
    <tr><td align="center"><label id="texto2">Tiempo en minutos</input></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="center"><input type="text" id="tiempo"></input></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="center"><form th:action="@{/automatico}" method="post"><button"> Programar </button></form></td></tr>
</table>
```

Querría pasar lo que escribo dentro de ese input de la fila del medio al pulsar el botón,quizá con @ModelAttribute? Intenté con esa anotación pero no saco nada en limpio, mi método POST está de la siguiente manera en este momento:

```
@PostMapping("/automatico")
    public String hacerAutomatico(@ModelAttribute("tiempo") String tiempo) {

        ...

        return "interfaz/index";
    }
```

En mi html hay insertado código javascript, que podría usar para pasar esta variable.

Answer (score 1):

Sin ser experto en *thymeleaf* creo que debe ser así:

```
public String hacerAutomatico(@RequestParam(value = "tiempo") String tiempo) {
    ...
}
```

pero insito - *thymeleaf* no es de mis preferidos.

**EDITADO**

No veo porque debes hacer algo con js o en html. Lo que veo es que haces mal el submit. Tu form esta en el td y el input que quieres que viaje está fuera del form. Haz algo así:

```
<table id="configurarAutomatizacion">
    <form th:action="@{/automatico}" method="post">
    <tr><td align="center"><label id="texto2">Tiempo en minutos</input></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="center"><input type="text" id="tiempo"></input></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="center"><button"> Programar </button></td></tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

Ahora cuando hagas submit el input viajará.

Otra cosa que no veo clara es el button. No debería de ser submit o algo parecido?

Comment: Esa parte la comprendo, y ahora me lo pide así que debe ser el camino correcto, el problema que arrastro es el que debo modificar en el HTML o JS para que reconozca lo que introduje en el <input>

Comment: Edito mi post...

Comment: Que sea button o submit en este caso no es demasiado importante, solo necesito un objeto que ejecute el método Post al pulsar sobre él, por otro lado, añadiendo también el text dentro del formulario sigue sin recoger el valor. Pero gracias igualmente!